# Regex to find whether the multiline String is without html tags or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to check whether the string with multiple lines contains any HTML tags(<>) in it or not.

```
var regex= /^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*$/;


console.log('istextWithoutHtml--', regex.test('Line1\nLine2'));\\ Expecting true, since it doesnt have html tags

\\ Expecting false for these combinations, since it contains html tags in it
\\ 'Line1<a>\nLine2'
\\ 'Line1\nLine2<p>'
\\ '<a></a>'
\\ '<\img>'
\\ '</a>\n</b>'
```

**Trial 1**

```
var regex1 = new RegExp(regex);
    
console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex1.test('Line1\nLine2')); \\ false (I am expecting true here)

console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex1.test('Line1<a>\nLine2')); \\ false
```

**Trial 2**

```
var regex2 = new RegExp(regex, 's');

console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex2.test('Line1\nLine2')); \\ true
console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex2.test('Line1<a>\nLine2')); \\ true (I am expecting false here)
```

**Trial 3**

```
var regex3 = new RegExp(regex, 'm');

console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex3.test('Line1\nLine2')); \\ true
console.log('istextWithoutHtml---', regex3.test('Line1<a>\nLine2')); \\ true (I am expecting false here)
```

Is there any way to achieve both HTML tag check in the multiple line string.

Comment: Did you try `/^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*/s.test(text)`? Or ``/^(?![^]*<[^>]+>)[^]*/.test(text)``

Comment: Second Regex worked fine, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok, posted with an  explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^(?![^]*<[^>]+>)[^]*/.test(text)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^]*<[^>]+>)` - immediately to the right, there should be no zero or more chars followed with `<`, one or more chars other than `>` and then a `>` char.
- `[^]*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible